# OpenLayers 2 - How to manually change coordinates of point?

Tags: extjs, html-lists, openlayers, gis, geoext

Is there any way to edit coordinates of the point manually?
I want to edit a point just like I create:

```
var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(newX,newY);
var point_ft = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, null);
warstwaRysowania.addFeatures(point_ft);
```

Can I do it similar to this example? If yes please tell me how. I want to work on the existing feature.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got a solution:

```
 function(e) {
            console.log(e.feature.geometry);
            var newPoint = new OpenLayers.LonLat(myX, myY);
            e.feature.move(newPoint);
            }
```